# expiration time of refresh token and access token in bing API

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-ads-api

Could anyone tell me what is default expiration time of refresh token and access token provided by Bing API?

Comment: 1 Hour(3600 Seconds)

Answer (score 1):

The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/authentication-oauth?view=bingads-12#managingoauthtokens) state the following:

> Refresh tokens are, and always will be, completely opaque to your application. They are long-lived e.g., **90 days** for public clients, but the app should not be written to expect that a refresh token will last for any period of time. Refresh tokens can be invalidated at any moment, and the only way for an app to know if a refresh token is valid is to attempt to redeem it by making a token request.

So basically, they recommend you as a developer not to rely on this time span.